# RP2040-Zero Not Blinking

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython, rp2040

so I am working on this project right now that is meant to connect an rp2040 zero to a 1.44" tft display using circuit python.

However, when trying to run examples and basic code from adafruit's own website, none of it worked. After doing some work to try and find the problem I decided to just work on the board and see if I could get that working. I installed mu editor and loaded a basic blink code onto the board. It wouldn't work so I tried finding any other way to make the LED blink and nothing will work.

This is my code now and this is the error I receive.

```python
import time
import board
import digitalio

led=digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.LED)
led.direciton = digitalio(Direction.OUTPUT)

while True:
    led.value = True
    time.sleep(0.5)
    led.value = False
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "code.py", line 29, in 
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LED'

Attempts listed above

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but something seems weird to me: the error message complains about line 29, but the code you showed has not even half that amount of lines... what is on line 29? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Also where have you assigned the LED to a specific pin

Comment: You're right. I mistakenly copy and pasted that from a different doc. The error was on line 5, but with the same issue. For some reason it doesn't recognize the board.LED() as an actual part of the module. LED was never defined anywhere, but I assumed that board.LED() would have dealt with that. I tried to find code with an LED definition but the same problem comes up

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [schematic of the RP2040 zero](https://cdn.robotshop.com/media/w/wav/rb-wav-359/pdf/rp2040-zero-pico-like-mcu-board-based-on-rp2040-mini-version-w-o-header-schematics.pdf) I can tell it has a type of smart LED called WS2812B, which is called a "Neopixel" by Adafruit.  You can't just turn it on by driving a digital output high, you have to send the specific type of signal it expects.  You might try running `import board; dir(board)` in a REPL to see if the `board` module provides anything useful.  Also try `import neopixel; dir(neopixel)`.

Answer (score 1):

**For Arduino C++ users:** Got mine working nicely with the FastLED add-on library (see https://fastled.io ):

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define NUM_LEDS 1
#define DATA_PIN 16 /* this is correct for RP2040-Zero */

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
bool alternate = false;

void setup() {
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
    leds[0] = (alternate = !alternate) ? CRGB::Red : CRGB::Green;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(500);
}
```